# NetBeans / BitBucket - "Git command returned with the following error: Read timeout after 45,000 ms"

Tags: netbeans, timeout, repository, clone, bitbucket

I am trying to clone a project from my BitBucket repository into Netbeans 8.0.

I have tried Team > Git > Clone...

...but it results in a "Git command returned with the following error: Read timeout after 45,000 ms" error.

Now, I ran a different test with a small HTML5 repository and that was cloned/imported fine, so the problem here must be to do with the size of the repository as it is 514MB.

So, is there a way I can increase or remove NetBeans' 45 second timeout, or do I need to both download the repository and set up a new project manually?

Comment: Try this:

Clone the repository locally with a different program. I use TortoiseGIT. 

Then in order to be managed by Netbeans: go to Team Menu and select Git->Clone

Comment: Thanks for your help, zlinks. I used Git Gui in the end to clone. And because I was cloning an entire NetBeans project, I could just go File > Open Project to open it. Would be great if NetBeans could do this as intended though. :/